# Is my calculation of the integral $\int \tan^{-1} x \, dx$ correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Compute $\int \tan^{-1}x \,dx$.

First, set $u = \arctan(x)$ and $dv = dx$. We want to find $du$ and we already have $v = x$.

We start by taking the tangent of both sides, leaving us with
$$\tan(u) = x.$$
Next, using implicit differentiation, we get $\frac{du}{dx}\sec^2(u) = 1$, or $$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sec^2(u)} = \frac{1}{1+ \tan^2(u)} = \frac{1}{1+ \tan^2(\arctan(x))} = \frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$

Therefore, $du = \frac{1}{x^2 +1}\, dx.$
We know that $\int u\, dv = uv - \int v\, du$ by Integration By Parts.
So, $\int \arctan(x)\, dx = x\arctan(x) - \int \frac{x}{x^2+1}\, dx.$

We can simplify $\int \frac{x}{x^2+1}\, dx$ by using u-substitution, making a different $u = x^2+1$ and $\frac{du}{2x} = dx.$
Subbing these in, we get
$$\int \frac{x}{u} \cdot \frac{du}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u}\, du = \frac{1}{2}|\log u| = \frac{1}{2}|\log(x^2+1)| + C.$$
Plugging this back into $x\arctan(x) - \int \frac{x}{x^2+1}\, dx,$ we get
$\boxed{x\arctan(x) - \frac{1}{2} |\log(x^2+1)| + C}$, where C is a constant.

Comment: Looks correct to me, but just to nag see that $x^2+1\geq 1$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and hence $log(x^2+1)\geq 0$ which implies that $|log(x^2+1)|=log(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, I guess I'll edit that. How do you write x∈R  in latex?

Comment: It would be `$x\in\Bbb R$`.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial.

Comment: It looks pretty good, but note that $\int\frac{du}{u}=\log |u| + C \ne | \log u | + C$.

Comment: Yep I noticed that as well and edited it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you can simply do like below
$$\int \arctan x~\mathrm{d}x= x\cdot \arctan x - \int \frac{x}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x =  x\cdot \arctan x - \frac{1}{2}\log (x^2+1) +C$$

Comment: Right but I have to explain each step in my proof.

Comment: @CSSJowoo Do you have trouble explaining any of the steps here? Even with added explanation this is shorter than yours, but that doesn't make yours wrong in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation of the integration by parts, which you combine with a change of variable, is a little tedious.

Using $x=\tan(u)$ which implies $dx=(\tan^2(u)+1)\,du$,

$$\int\arctan(x)\,dx=\int u(\tan^2(u)+1)\,du=u\tan(u)-\int\tan(u)\,du$$

and back to the original variable with $u=\arctan(x)$,

$$\int\arctan(x)\,dx=x\arctan(x)-\int\frac x{x^2+1}\,dx.$$

---

It is more direct to assume a factor $1$ and integrate it,

$$\int\arctan(x)\,dx=\int1\arctan(x)\,dx=x\arctan(x)-\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}.$$

---

You could as well have continued with the change of variable:

$$\int\tan(u)\,du=-\int\frac{d\cos(u)}{\cos(u)}=-\log(|\cos(u)|)$$

and

$$\cos(u)=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$